# c# reading xls file not working when microsoft office Excel is not installed?

Tags: c#, excel, windows, iis, windows-server-2008

I've just published my app to my windows Server to run my app with IIS.
In my program, I read from an xls file to populate a table in my application.
I'm unable to find out the exact cause, as it just throws a '500' at me.
I'm wondering if its possible that my server is unable to 'open' the XLS file for reading its content? 
If so, would installing Microsoft Excel on my Windows Server solve this issue?

The program works on my development computer, which ofcource has Microsoft Excel installed.
This is the only difference I can spot.

Kind regards!

requested code:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<List<String>> ReadXLS()
{

// read from xls
WorkBook workbook = WorkBook.Load("C:\\animals.xls");
```

This works on my local machine, but not on my server, even tho I save the xls on the same location on my server.`

Comment: What library are you using? If it's excel interop, it requires Excel installed. There are other libraries that you can use that don't require.

Comment: I'm using ironxl's library, so you also think its because Excel isnt installed? so I was on the right path :D

Comment: Well, I don't know the library, [but its page](https://ironsoftware.com/csharp/excel/) says that you don't need Excel installed, so there is another problem. With the information that you posted is hard to tell what's wrong, you should post an MCVE. Also, make sure that all required libraries are being deployed to prodution.

Comment: Regarding the Javascript thing, that's a completely different question, please, limit your posts to one question each.

Comment: I cannot spot a problem in the "using" statements, does that mean that these libraries are imported correctly?

Comment: I've updated my question to keep it simple :)

Comment: As I said, please, post an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: I've tried my best to show you whats happening. see Update :-)

Comment: Applications when connected to a server should always be run from client.  The users have very limited access to access to the IIS server.

Comment: I'm sorry but you confused me a little over there, do you mean that the xls file is unaccessible by the user pool using my app?

Comment: 1) You are doing Office automation, which requires Office. 2) You are doing server side Office automation, which is widely discussed and not supported by Microsoft, https://support.microsoft.com/en-ca/help/257757/considerations-for-server-side-automation-of-office So there is not much to talk about it.